# How to add data points to a bar graph as horizontal lines instead of columns in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to combine two data sets in one bar graph where one set is displayed as bars and the other as horizontal lines at the y-axis point where the top of the bar would be, like this:

[image]

Here is some code to start with:

```
df <- data.frame(X=c("X1","X2","X3"),
                 Y=c(3,5,2),
                 Y2=c(2.5,5.7,3.2))


g_bar <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y,)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge",colour=NA)

g_bar
```

Any ideas? Thanks.